# black border when clicking data table

Tags: primefaces

When i put a p:dataTable inside a dialog with de 'scrollable = true', 'liveScroll = true', when i click this dataTable a black border appears, and i couldn't find a css that was making this happen. i didnt find anything online about this.
code of the p:dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{dashboardBean.listaTarefas}" var="tarefa" emptyMessage="#{msg['message.nao.foram.encontradas.pendencias.para.este.evento']}" styleClass="borderless"
                    scrollable="true" scrollRows="20" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="280" >
```

Image of the black border:

[image: Text]

Comment: Check your CSS.  Its probably some focus border.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a **border** it's an [**outline**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp), to remove it add this in your css file.

```css
ui-datatable-scrollable-body, .ui-state-focus {
    outline: 0
}
```

Add `ui-state-focus` if you want to remove **outline** from *sortable columns*, and from *rows per page select menu*.